# Passing all data from json in ionic through api to user page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on this particular ionic app which is giving me a serious headache. I am not yet familiar with ionic but I was able to create the login page and registration page successfully.

My main issue is returning all values been fetch from database through my api when user's login details is valid to the user's profile page. I want the user's details(username and email) to be pass from one page to the other after successful login.

Below is my source code.

**Login.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");        

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);

    }

  require "config.php";

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    if (isset($data)) {

        $request = json_decode($data);

        $username = $request->username;

        $password = $request->password;

                }

      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);

      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

       $username = stripslashes($username);

      $epassword = encryptIt($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$epassword'";

      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



      // If result matched myusername and mypassword, table row must be 1 row                    

      if($count >0) {

     $response= "Your Login success";


      }else {

    $response= "Your Login Email or Password is invalid";         

      }

 echo json_encode( $response);
```

**Login.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions}  from "@angular/http";
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})


export class LoginPage {

  @ViewChild("username") username;

  @ViewChild("password") password;

  data:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
     private http: Http, public loading: LoadingController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  registerPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
  }


  signIn(){

    //// check to confirm the username and password fields are filled

    if(this.username.value=="" ){

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

    title:"ATTENTION",

    subTitle:"Username field is empty",

    buttons: ['OK']

    });

    alert.present();

    } else

    if(this.password.value==""){

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

    title:"ATTENTION",

    subTitle:"Password field is empty",

    buttons: ['OK']

    });

    alert.present();

    }

    else

    {

    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = {

    username: this.username.value,

    password: this.password.value

    };

    let loader = this.loading.create({

    content: 'Processing, please wait…',

    });

    loader.present().then(() => {

    //this.http.post('http://localhost:90/totallight/api/login.php',data,options)

    this.http.post('http://edomonitor.com/school-evaluation-api/login.php',data,options)

    .map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(res => {

    console.log(res)

    loader.dismiss()

    if(res=="Your Login success"){

    //Store all json data and pass them to UserPage

    /*let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

    title:"CONGRATS",

    subTitle:(res),

    buttons: ['OK']

    });

    alert.present();*/   
    }else

    {

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

    title:"ERROR",

    subTitle:"Invalid username/password",

    buttons: ['OK']

    });

    alert.present();

    }

    });

    });

    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to create new service to handle Auth requests

Then you can call function like below after successful login response

```
this.authService.setToken(data.token, data.id, data.name, data.email);
```

Then in AuthService.ts add new method to store login user data

```
setAccessToken(token: string, id: number, name: string, email: string) {

    this._accessToken = token;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;

    // Save to Storage for future reference 

    this._storage.set('loggedInUser', {
      token: token,
      id: id,
      name: name,
      email: email
    });

    // Log User 
    this._events.publish('user:login');
}
```

then add beloved code in app.components.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._events.subscribe('user:login', (userEventData) => {
      this.rootPage = HomePage;
   }
}
```

Then you will able to get user data in any pages like

### HomePage.ts

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    private _auth: AuthService,
  ) {}
}
```

### HomePage.html

```
<h2 class="user-name>{{ _auth.name }} </h2>
```

Comment: hello Krishna, thanks for your reply. I so much appreciate your time. Please I want to ask, if you take a look at my Login.php, when i fetched those data from database, do I need to add them to response i.e $response= $row['email']; or I just leave it out.

Comment: can return response like `return ['operation' => 'success', 'data' => $row];`

Comment: I am sorry for asking too much, but could you show me how I can put that inside  if($count >0) {

     $response= "Your Login success";


      }else {

    $response= "Your Login Email or Password is invalid";         

      }

Comment: @Sampath, please could you help me with this.